# Retrieve DIV-content inside a Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, if-statement

I have been searching for help from various forums and similar posts, but without any progress. 
I have three pages, one that lets me insert information about projects into my database, a second that show the images and names of every project in the database, and a third page which I want to have a function that shows the image and name of the selected project in the second page.

Code on the second page(dashboardadmin.php):

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wildfire");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql= "SELECT pid, project_name, image, image_type FROM project";   

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {


echo "<form action='omprojekt.php' method='post'>

<div id='comp' name='comp'>
    <img src=pic.php?pid=".$row['pid']." width=100xp height=100xp/>"." ".$row['project_name']."
</div>

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Choose' />
   </form>";


}
}

else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

        ?>
```

Code on the third page (omprojekt.php):

```
<?php
   /* Tried both of the $val variables but of course only one at a time. This is only to show you what I have tried. */

$val = isset($_POST['comp']) ? $_POST['comp'] : '';
$val = $_POST['comp']; 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

echo "$val";
}

?>
```

In the last code you can see that I have two `$val` variables, but I have only used one of them at a time in my codes. The purpose of showing both of them here is to show you that I have tried both of them.

What I want to do is to make the third page show the image and name of the selected project in the second page. As you see, I have tried to retrieve the content from the DIV using the same "name". The problem is that the third page(omprojekt.php) doesn't show any content at all, and not even any errors.

Comment: You don't actually send any data to the third thing from the second. I'm not even sure what data you're wanting to pass. What you could do is add a hidden element to the form containing the value of `$row['pid']`  and then define the img tag to use that data as you have with the second page.

Comment: `<div id='comp' name='comp'>` - divs do NOT bear the name attribute and isn't a form element. so `$val = isset($_POST['comp']) ? $_POST['comp'] : '';` will not take in the value you're trying to pass as a name attribute in your div.

Comment: @Jon Stirling I want to pass the image and name that the button contains. There is many buttons an every button contains a image and name. So I want to pass the image and name of the specific/clicked button to the third page.

Comment: @Fred ii Do you have any suggestion, please? I have been trying to fix this struggle for a whole week now.

Comment: see the answers given below

Comment: By the way, this is invalid syntax `width=100xp height=100xp` - it's `px` and not `xp`. "XP"'s are really old computers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're expecting the div to submit like an input, but it won't, because it's not an input. So put it in an input.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        // Don't use and id attribute because you're in a loop and you might have multiple id's with the same value.
        echo "<form action='omprojekt.php' method='post'>
            <div> 
                <img src=pic.php?pid=".$row['pid']." width=100xp height=100xp/>"." ".$row['project_name']."
            </div>
            <input type='hidden' name='pid' value='".$row['pid']."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='project_name' value='".$row['project_name']."'>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Choose' />
       </form>";
    }
}
```

Then on the next page,

```
$val = (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['project_name'])) ? 
    "<img src=pic.php?pid={$_POST['pid']} width=100xp height=100xp/> {$_POST['project_name']}" : '';
```

For the sake of completeness, there are a few other things wrong with your code.

1) The width and height attributes on the iamge should have quotes, and do not accept "px", they are just numbers. If you want to use "px" you should use style instead. `<img src='' style='width:20px; height:20px;' />`

2) You should be [escaping user input before running it through your query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: `// For display,...` that is part of actual code and WILL throw a syntax error. Place that as a comment below or above that code for an explanation. OP might think otherwise.

Comment: then `width=100xp height=100xp` another syntax error. As you can see, I'm not downvoting you for wrong syntax. I like to give people the benefit of the doubt first ;-) - then you're leaving the OP open to an SQL injection with `$_POST['project_name']` and `$_POST['pid']`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it wouldn't have thrown an error, but it would have echo'd to the page. Fixed it, thank you.

Comment: it would have in HTML source ;-) and you're welcome.

Comment: you need to fix this `width=100xp height=100xp`

Comment: Thanks fred, I made a note at the bottom.

Comment: *my duh* lol I noticed it's the OP's syntax error. ah, so you copied their code, got it. *grazie* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Data will only be sent from a `<form>` to the `action` script if it exists in an `<input...>` HTML tag. You cannot pick data out of randon `<DIV>` tags etc.

So you could do this by using a `hidden` input field like this ( this is only one way )

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {


       echo "<form action='omprojekt.php' method='post'>

             <div>
                <img src=pic.php?pid=".$row['pid'] .
                  " style="width:100px;height:100px" /> " .
                  $row['project_name']."
             </div>

             <input type='hidden' name='comp' value='" . $row['pid'] . "' />
             <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Choose' />
             </form>";


    }
}
```

Now when you get to `omprojekt.php` the `$_POST['comp']` variable will exist.

You can have as many hidden input fields as you like so if you want to pass the project_name as well just add another hidden field.

Comment: -1 because 1) you left off a closing curly, which may be confusing. 2) you don't know that this is only outputting a single form and you did not address the issue of multiple id's.

Comment: @Pamblam Fixed the missing `}`

Comment: it's in the question. The div he's trying to submit as a form is in a loop and has an id. If his query returns more than one row, he will have multiple id's.

Comment: @Pamblam Ah yes. Actually his code is creating multiple small forms, a strange but completely legal way of doing things. So now I believe I have fixed all your complaints, can you verify?